# Upi Hyperlink not getting called url

Tags: android, ios, payment, upi

I am trying to add upi hyperlink on web.
With following format
upi://pay?pa=myvpa@ybl&pn=abc%20pqr&tr=B1947&tn=Pay%20to%20abc%20pqr&am=1&mam=null&cu=INR&url=https://example.com/testUpiPay

Tried on android, upi app is getting opened and able to make transaction but url (https://example.com/testUpiPay) passed doesn't called.

In iOS, the available options are not complete (only shows whatsapp, not showing phonepe, paytm and others).

Can anyone help me if getting atleast response at my url for android devices.

Comment: Same passed url doesn't called. Have you solve this "url" parameter issue ?

Comment: Not able to solve this issue yet.

Comment: Hi , Have you found any solution for the above issue ?

Comment: No solution found for this issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

url parameter in the upi URL will not be called by UPI Apps automatically. This url will be used and provided as a link in the UPI Apps after the payment success to download the bills, etc. Until otherwise a user clicks on this URL, it will not be hit automatically by the UPI Apps.